# C# | Assigning new class to interface object

Tags: c#

Here is the code I currently have, the question follows after:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var obj1 = new A();
        obj1.DoIt();
        obj1.SetFlyBehavior(new BehaviorB());
        obj1.DoIt();

        string input = Console.ReadLine();
    }
};

class BaseOfA
{
    protected ObjectBehavior behavior;

    public void DoIt()
    {
        behavior.DoIt();
    }

    public void SetBehavior(ObjectBehavior ob) {
      behavior = ob;  
    }

};

class A : BaseOfA {
    public A() {
        behavior = new BehaviorA(); 
    }
}

interface ObjectBehavior {
    void DoIt();
}

class BehaviorA : ObjectBehavior {
    void ObjectBehavior.DoIt() {
        Console.WriteLine("Behavior: A");
    }
}

class BehaviorB : ObjectBehavior {
    void ObjectBehavior.DoIt() {
        Console.WriteLine("Behavior: B");
    }
}
```

Now my question is, in this case, how am I going to make it work so that I can assign both `BehaviorA` and `BehaviorB` to instance `obj1` as long as they implement `ObjectBehavior`?

Comment: assign to what?

Comment: Why6 would you want to do that?  You would never be sure what behavior you would get unless you re/set it each time

Comment: You havent been clear what you are trying to achieve. From what you've said and the code you have given. It appears you have done what you want??

Comment: Thank you for your reply. What i'm trying to do is exactly in the code, however it doesn't accept this. A.SetFlyBehavior(new BehaviorB); is not ok. It gives me the following error: Argument 1: Cannot convert from BehaviorB to ObjectBehavior. So i want to be able to set the different behavior class.

Comment: Where is SetFlyBehaviour in this code?

Comment: The solution could be the `decorator pattern`

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `obj.SetFlyBehaviour` this method is not defined anywhere. The method you define on BaseOfA is called `SetBehaviour`. Once that is fixed the code you gave compiles fine for me